# My Aspire A-515-54 fails to boot. Got a software disk assembly mismatch

Tags: partitioning, grub2, initramfs

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed 9 weeks ago. Windows 10/11 deleted, disk reformatted NTFS.  System worked like a charm for over a month. Then problem appeared.

I tried the command /etc/fstab to update the UUIDs. My computer has a file /etc/fstab with no contents. An empty file.

Next, I tried sudo e2fck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sda. This command e2fck is "not found." The system will recognize but will not boot from a bootable thumb drive. This t-drive was used to instal Ubuntu 22.04.

I have access to the grub recovery commands and the initramfs commands. SUGGESTIONS?   Robert Thomas

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is not a command.

Comment: If `/etc/fstab` is empty, there must be some serious issues with your installation, because it has a central role in setting up your file system.